# R - Change value in one column based on NA value in another column

Tags: r, if-statement, transform

I am working on a dataset which has information about the education of users.

I want to change a value in the Freq column to "0" based on a NA value in Var1. So if Var1 = NA, then Freq = 0.

[image: See picture]

For the life of me I can not figure it out and need some help.

Do any of you guys know how to deal with this?

Comment: Things are always made easier for people trying to help you if you can provide some sample data. In the meantime, review the `dplyr` library and the `mutate()` function therein along with `ifelse()` statements.

Comment: please do not post images to clarify your problem instead of "real" code. The question quality is important for us to helpyou and for other users to find their answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: `Freq[is.na(Var1)] <- 0` should work. You can't evaluate missingness with `==NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

```
library(dplyr)

#Some data
dat <- 
  data.frame(var1 = sample(c(1:3, rep(NA, 5)), 10, TRUE), 
             var2 = rnorm(10), 
             freq = rnorm(10, 100))

#The "dplyr" way
dat %>%
  mutate(freq = ifelse(is.na(var1), 0, freq))

#subset/replace from AdamO
dat$freq[is.na(dat$var1)] <- 0
```